# Prolog variable as functor

Tags: prolog

I want to create this prolog program: the user input - or +, if - the result is 3-2, else is 3+2. I wrote this program but the compiler gives me error. What can i do ?

```
try(B):-
    read(A),
    B is A(3,2).
```

Answer (score 6):

A couple of issues.

In Prolog, a functor cannot be a variable. You can use `call(Functor, arg1, arg2, ...)`. So instead of `A(3,2)` you'd write, `call(A, 3, 2)`.

You're not out of the woods yet, though. In Prolog, you cannot define your own arithmetic operation that `is/2` will recognize. `is/2` only works with the built in arithmetic operations. So using `call` won't help you in that case.

You can, however, build the term that `is/2` will recognize, using `=../2`. `=../2` provides an equivalence between a term and a list:

```
functor(x, y, ...) =.. [functor, x, y, ...]
```

You can use it this way:

```
read_and_execute_op(Result) :-
    read(Operator),
    ArithmeticTerm =.. [Operator, 3, 2],   % This builds a term, +(3,2)
    Result is ArithmeticTerm.
```